How to create a Snowflake Storage Integration with GCP Bucket with Terraform?
I am trying to see how to create a terraform module for Snowflake Storage Integration with GCP Bucket using storage_gcp_service_account.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Snowflake-Labs/snowflake/latest/docs/resources/storage_integration
